# how to derive t-statistic for alpha (Eq. 15.29) in "quantitative equity portfolio management"?

Tags: statistics, statistical-significance

I am reading "quantitative equity portfolio management: an active approach to portfolio construction and management" by Ludwig B. Chincarini, Daehwan Kim, and am confused by this derivation of t-statistic for alpha (Eq. 15.29) in the book:

[image]

where $\hat{\alpha}$ is the estimate for model alpha, $\hat{\omega}$ is estimate of the residual standard deviation, $T$ is total number of data points, $r_{B,t}^*$ is the benchmark return at time t (minus risk-free return), $\bar{r}_{B,t}^*$ is its average.

By definition, t-statistic is:

$$t = \frac{\hat{\alpha}}{std(\hat{\alpha})}$$

Does anyone know how we can derive 15.29 from this definition?

Thank you!

Comment: The Alpha is the intercept in a Linear Regression. Start with the complete set of formulas for regression of y on x and you will see that t(alpha) it is basically the 15.29 formula (with differences in notation, T versus N etc.) i.e. alpha is divided by the standard deviation of alpha https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~dickey/summer_institute/formulas  Then look up the derivation in any statistics book that covers least squares regression